# Using UIImagePNGRepresentation

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to save a UIImageView image to a png file, and then use that file as a GLTexture.
I'm having trouble with this, when I try to run my code in the simulator, Xcode says it succeeded, but the simulator crashes with no error messages.
Here is my code:

```
NSString *dataFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Picture.png"];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
[imageData writeToFile:dataFilePath atomically:YES];

// Load image into texture
loadTexture("Picture.png", &Input, &renderer);
```

Comment: Make sure the build configuration in the upper left is set to Debug (e.g., "Simulator -- 3.0 | Debug"), and do **Build > Build and Debug**.  Then do **Run > Console** to view your console.  That should show you your error messages.

Comment: also check dataFilePath and imageData... anyone of them NULL? Do Path has valid string?

Comment: When I run the Build & Debug and view the Console, I find that the problem is that my "Picture.png" file is not found.  How can I get my UIImageView to save to a png file that I can use within my app?

Comment: I've also tried this code, and my app still does not respond to using the Picture.png in my texture. Help?
// Save the image 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
NSString *imagePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
NSString *filename = @"Picture.png" ; 
NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imagePath, filename] ;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)];
[imageData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
// Load image into texture
loadTexture("Picture.png", &Input, &renderer);

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your reply to Metalmi, it looks like you're not giving us the actual code you're compiling. If you're actually doing what it looks like you're doing, then you're trying to write data to your application's bundle, which is going to fail because you're **not allowed to do that**. Can you provide us with the exact code you're trying to execute?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Picture" ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am getting this error message "Assertion failed: (CGImage), function loadTexture, file Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”."
Here's my code:// Save the image 
NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Picture" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
  [imageData writeToFile:dataFilePath atomically:YES];
// Load image into texture
loadTexture("Picture.png", &Input, &renderer);
And the line it crashes at:
CGImageRef CGImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]].CGImage;
rt_assert(CGImage);

Comment: iOS apps cannot write inside their own bundles.